# Kendo Calendar with two-four months view

Tags: jquery, calendar, kendo-ui

I was wondering how can i have two months view in Kendo Calendar as my client wants to have a calendar with two months and one with four months at a time.

Thanks in Advance,
Sher

Comment: it was available in Telerik ASP .Net controls but i am not sure about Telerik MVC Controls.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a way to do this with the latest version of Kendo UI. You're pretty limited on some of the configuration options with widgets like the date picker.

See all configuration options here:
http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/datepicker